# Delphi Arabic character display issue on android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

i am using arabic characters for the first time in my app

this is how they should look like :

[image]

**But this is how they end up :**

[image]

things i tried:

- changed the phone language to arabic.
- i chose this font  :Arabic type settings.  i found in the fonts list

[image]

things works well for windows, its only in Android i get the problem.
i believe i am missing something because i never used arabic in apps  before.
i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fire Monkey does not support right-to-left languages like Arabic. Unfortunately your chosen framework is not capable of meeting your needs. You will need to find a different tool to write your app.

Comment: i found this component https://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiandroid/  hopefully it will do it.

Comment: I'd use Java personally but I don't known what constraints you have

Comment: @Someone Unfortunately the component is only compatible with Delphi `XE5/XE6/XE7` and you are using `10-Seattle` .

Comment: Ouch, this is some bad news.

Comment: I guess i will use images as buttons :(

Comment: There are plenty of options. No need to be tied to Delphi.

Comment: @Jerry - I would hardly call this "news".  FMX has been notoriously incomplete w.r.t LTR languages right from the start (http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=98644).

Comment: @Deltics Sarcasm intended.